# Why I am getting a fresh new installed ubuntu 12.04 on each restart?

Tags: 12.04, installation, startup, hp

Why I am getting a fresh new installed ubuntu 12.04 on each restart?
Every time I turnoff my laptop and start it again or restart,I get a fresh copy of ubuntu 12.04 as i'd installed it.Even my folders made on desktop doesn't stay there.!
Why it is happening? :-O
I am using HP-pavilion-Notebook-g6-1004tx
Please help me to come out of this problem.

Comment: that is weird indeed. Are you logging into the guest session by any chance? Do you log on your own user account (get prompted for password when you log into your system)? Some more info would be helpful. let us know!

Comment: When did you installed it , is it occurring after updating .Also how many user accounts have you created , Are you logging as root or user or guest. Apologies for too many Questions , but this is most weirdly interesting question i read since long time.

Comment: It's okay dear.
I am logging as user.
I have created only one account named "SILENCE".
No, I tried to update it but after a complete update of 264 MB I do restart my lappy,and it seems like a BORN BABY!!! Changed wallpaper also reverts!!!

Comment: Checked to make sure you don't still have the installation media in your CD drive or whatever?

Comment: No dude...It isn't..

Comment: Yep, may be he is logging in guest session :) That's the only reason I could think of.

Comment: I am logging as user. I have created only one account named "SILENCE". No, I tried to update it but after a complete update of 264 MB I do restart my lappy,and it seems like a BORN BABY!!! Changed wallpaper also reverts!!! 

Ya,I get prompted each login time for my password.

Comment: I am really eager to find the problem. Though re-installation is recommended ( as accepted) .But for the sake of such a problem i am really interested in the reason behind it :D

Comment: ok.me too..but i've updated it 7 times and still gets the same stuff..!
I gave up,,.but thanks for support tijybba.....

Comment: Does it remember the account "SILENCE" when it reboots? From where do you boot (hard disk, USB stick,etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

Okay presuming your installation is on a usb stick installed with Universal USB Installer or like program and is in persistent mode check if there is an caper-rw icon is in the launcher if no then you have two options you need to reinstall the os using Universal USB Installer or like program and set the persistent file to th capacity of the usb stick not more.The other solution is to create the casper-rw file while in ubuntu follow the link to do so http://www.pendrivelinux.com/how-to-create-a-larger-casper-rw-loop-file/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstallation?
It will help you to solve it.
wish you a very good luck.
:)